# C++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS, argv[]

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access, command-line-arguments

I've been stuck on this for a while and can't debug this `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.  I have run NSZombie and I am pretty sure its a memory issue with `argv[1]` (or anything more for that matter). I've checked my syntax and libraries so I don't know why it wont store past `arg[0]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Enter the initial bankroll" << endl;
    int bankroll = atoi(argv[1]); //code faults here

    cout << "Enter seed" << endl;
    int seed = atoi(argv[2]);

    // ...
```

I left out the rest because the error occurs before anything else.

The code runs in the terminal but fails the automatic grader for my class.

Arguments entered:

> ./blackjack 400 1

Should work for any numbers.

Shouldn't `argv[0]` would be blackjack, `argv[1]` the first number and `argv[2]` the second?

Comment: You "_believe_" or you **know**? There is a **big** difference....

Comment: Sorry. Let me edit and put more specifics.

Comment: you said you get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but the program runs in the terminal? where does the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` happen? With the automatic grader?

Comment: I think this is a question you should ask to the people who designed the autograder. I suspect you aren't meant to use command line arguments but are supposed to redirect cin so that it reads from a file. But who knows, I don't think this is a question anyone here can answer.

Answer (score 5):

`cout` **doesn't** fill the elements of `argv`, those come from the command line used to execute your program. Also, whenever you use `argv`, be sure to check `argc`, which is the number of valid indices into `argv`. Your program is probably crashing because you *haven't* passed any arguments to your program, and so the elements of `argv` aren't usable.

You'll need to use `cin` calls to read the user input that you're expecting, or change your program to use values passed in from the command line, i.e. no prompts or reads.

Your added assumptions are correct about `argv`: if you execute the program with: `./blackjack 400 1`, then `argv[1]` should be `400`, and `argv[2]` should be `1`.

Since, based on your edit, you seem to want to get these numbers from the command-line, then remove your `cout` calls.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that the OP wants to read with `cin`, but has somehow got that confused with command line arguments. It's such a strange misunderstanding to have that I didn't see it at first.

Comment: @pb2q The project must use command line arguments to get the seed and bankroll variables otherwise cin would be much simpler! :)

Comment: When I run the program from terminal it runs. However, in Xcode when I Build and Run at the bottom it says: GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" (but it still says Succeeded in right bottom corner).   In Hypergrade our auto grader it just get as far as the first cout and then fails.

Comment: @pb2q Also, I have entered arguments.  The only reason the cout is there is because the autograder checks character by character and shows them in the correct output example.  (They don't do anything; not sure why autograder wants it to 'cout' "Enter seed" when the seed has already been entered when starting the program)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted argv are command line arguments.  If they are filled you just use them.  I often do like this:

```
int
main(int n_app_args, char** app_arg)
{
  std::string nec_file;
  if (n_app_args > 1)
    nec_file = app_arg[1];
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Enter NEC output file: ";
    std::cin >> nec_file;
  }
```

where if I forget the command line argument the program asks me.  If I remember the argument the argument is used without further intervention.  You can obviously extend this to more arguments.